# Pandoc loading images but not latex files from input subfolder

Tags: latex, pandoc

I've got a latex document that I publish as a pdf, but I need to share it with reviewers in Word .docx format. I've got some images and a bunch of graphs in tikz format in a separate .tex files in a figures subfolder. I've defined `input@path{{figures/}}` so that I don't have to put the path into each `\input{blah.tex}` call. This works just fine when I publish the document as a pdf, but when I try to use pandoc to create the docx I get a `[WARNING] Could not load include file` error for the .tex files, though the images load fine.

As far as I can tell, pandoc should be able to load files from subfolders and the input@path should set it up ([this post discuses how to use pandoc parameters to define the input@path](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/220756/how-to-set-input-global-directory-to-graphicspath)).

I'm sure this is some basic lack of understanding on my part, but here's a minimum non-working example:

example.tex:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,letterpaper]{article}

\makeatletter
\def\input@path{{figures/}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
  \centering
  \caption{Tikz Example}
  \input{exTikz.tex}
  \label{fig:exTikz}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

And the exTikz.tex (lifted from https://latex-tutorial.com/tutorials/tikz/)

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw [red,dashed] (-2.5,2.5) rectangle (-1.5,1.5) node [black,below] {Start}; % Draws a rectangle
  \draw [thick] (-2,2) % Draws a line
  to [out=10,in=190] (2,2)
  to [out=10,in=90] (6,0)
  to [out=-90,in=30] (-2,-2);
  \draw [fill] (5,0.1) rectangle (7,-0.1) node [black,right] {Obstacle}; % Draws another rectangle
  \draw [red,fill] (-2,-2) circle [radius=0.2] node [black,below=4] {Point of interest}; % Draws a circle
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I have also tried `--resource-path=figures` to no avail.

I realize that in order to use the graphs in a .docx I'm going to need to use a lua-filter to convert the tikz's to png ala [this post](https://latex-tutorial.com/tutorials/tikz/), but first I need to pandoc to actually access the `\begin{tikzpicture}` segments stuck in the various .tex files before it will apply the filter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pandoc does not support the `\input@path` parameter. You could open a feature request [here](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/new).

I suggest to use TeX to compile the Ti*k*Z packages into proper graphics, e.g. with the method described [in this Q&A](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44505/export-tikz-figures-to-pdf), then use `\renewcommand` to change `\input` to `\includegraphics`, which pandoc will understand. This will also allow to make use of the `--resource-path` option.

Comment: It doesn't support it!?! Bloody hell. I wasted a lot of time under the impression that it does due to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/220756/how-to-set-input-global-directory-to-graphicspath). These TikZs are all output from R, so I'll just output every thing to proper graphics from there and update things appropriately. Thanks heaps for the answer!

Comment: Happy to hear :) The Q&A in the link is about someone using pandoc to create PDFs via LaTeX, they use `\input@path` in their pandoc template. So it's basically reading LaTeX vs. writing LaTeX; the latter is much easier and allows to make use of more LaTeX features.